# Unable to call Com+ from vb6 code

Tags: .net, vb6, com+

I created a C# dll in vs 2010 with all Com+ attributes.i created a strong key,and
`this strong key to Application properties`
`and  register it to the assembly:`
`sn -k ComPlusClass.snk`

`Use VS tool to register the assembly as:`
`regasm ComPlusExample.DLL`

`Create a Type Library using the tool:`
`    tlbexp ComPlusExample.DLL

`Register it in COM+ as:`
`regsvcs ComPlusExample.DLL`
later i created a application in vb6 and add  generated .tlb in refrences.Everthing works fine. I am able to call c# dll from vb6. But i need to give this code to my client and it is not possible to run all these steps there.
So for this i created exe by right click my app in COM+.i installed this exe on my client system.but when i added the refrence of tlb from progmramfiles it shows a error that `module can't be found`.plz help me in this regard.Is creating exe is the right way to export my com+ from one system to another..

Answer (score 0):

Your application relies on the .NET Framework so the "regsvcs" command must be run on the client machine in which you are deploying. If you simply export the library and import into COM+ I don't believe the necessary CCW (COM callable wrapper) entries are added to the Windows registry.

I would therefore recommend creating a batch file that runs the "regsvcs" command with the parameters you need. You will not need to generate the TLB file on the client since this is used at development time only.

Of course you could also create a project installer that does this for you but if you are looking for a quick solution the batch file will do it.